# Periodic antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's consider an integral $\int{\ln(a \cdot \sin(x)+1) \cdot dx}=F(x)$. The value of $a$ is choisen so that $F(x)$ is a periodic function. Find $a$.

Ideas: If $F(x)$ is periodic with a period $T$, then $F(x+T)=F(x)$, $f(x+T)=f(x)$, according to this we can state that if $F$ has a period, then $f$ also has one. (But not on the contrary, becuase $f=const$ is a counterexample).

$\ln(a \sin(x)+1)=\ln(a \cdot sin(x+T)+1)$, $a \sin(x)=a \cdot sin(x+T)$, $a(sin(x)-sin(x+T))=0$. If $a=0$, then the work is done - it suits our requiremtnets.
If $a \neq 0$, then $sin(x)=sin(x+T)$ - if this works for all $x \in dom(f)$, then in particular it works for $x=0$. We get $\sin(T)=0, T=\pi t, t in \mathbb{Z}$.

Working with $sin(x)=sin(x+\pi t)$ we can also determine that $t=2q+1,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. But it's not a sort of result, which may help a lot. What can i do more?

Comment: Are you required to have $F$ defined on all of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: In this case $dom(F)=dom(f)$.

Comment: Do we need $\text{dom} f=\Bbb R$?